# How can I get a object item from sqlite db?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am looking for a simple and efficient way to get a custom object from sqlite db.
There is some moudle provide similar function such as `sqlobject`.
But my purpose is very simple:
I want to save data with normal sql statement like `cur.execute("create table point(x INTEGER,y INTEGER)")`
and get data by `cur.execute('select x,y as "p [Point]" from point')`,
Then `cur.fetchone()[0]` will return a `Point` object.
Sqlite official document has a way to save and retrieve an object [at here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#letting-your-object-adapt-itself).
They register a adapter and a converter for Point class which does not correspond my aim only use the converter.

In simple words,I don't want to register a adapter in sqlite. Register a custom type will make it difficult to query a metadata, so I just want to convert the data to a custom type when I retrieve data.Of course,I can use a custom function to put them into custom object after I get the data .But I don't think this way is so simple and efficient.

So, what is the best way to solve this problem simply and efficiently?

Comment: If you find the [SQLite and Python types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite-and-python-types) section of the manual hard to understand any other mechanism will be even more complicated. Doug Hellmann's excellent Python Method of the Week covers the [custom type mechanism](http://pymotw.com/2/sqlite3/) of `sqlite3` which you might find helpful.

Comment: You asked a similar question yesterday, we can't really make you understand it. Take the examples, change them, break them, learn from them and you will eventually understand it. There is no Royal Road to understanding sqlite3 class adapters.

Comment: @msw The example you provided is really useful,thank you.But I do not want to register a type in sqlite. Register a custom type will make it difficult to query a metadata, so I just want to convert the data to a custom type when I retrieve data.Of course,I can use a custom function to put them into custom object after I get the data .But I think this way is not so simple and efficient.

Comment: It is not sqlite you are registering a type with - it is in the interface between Python and sqlite. Following the Python manual, `x` and `y` are two simple int columns, which when retrieved are cast into a `Point`-class.
Registering a type as per the manual does not alter the sqlite libraries or databases - the adapter and converter only exists in the Python module where you are setting the adapter and converter up (and associated modules that load said module).

Comment: @MrGumble Yes,you are right.My expression is not very appropriate,it's adapter not type.As the official example,an adapter change a class object to a string which can be recognize by sqlite db,then it would be difficult to query a metadata, that's what I want to express.So I just want to make a special converter lonely,only use for casting retrieved data to a class.But I don't not how to achieve a converter in low level.

Comment: @android.ikaros You want to query a metadata. What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). There are several available for Python. A notable one is [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).